# selecting number of leaf nodes of dendrogram in heatmap.2 in R

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram, hclust, dendextend

In Matlab you can designate the number of nodes in a dendrogram that you wish to plot as part of the `dendrogram` function: `dendrogram(tree,P)` generates a dendrogram plot with no more than P leaf nodes.

My attempts to do the same with `heatmap2` in R have failed miserably. The posts to stackoverflow and biostars have suggested using `cutree` but `heatmap2` gets stuck with postings' suggestions on `Rowv` option.  Here "TAD" is the data matrix 8 columns by 831 rows.

```
# cluster it
hr <- hclust(dist(TAD, method="manhattan"), method="average")

# draw the heat map
heatmap.2(TAD, main="Hierarchical Cluster",
          Rowv=as.dendrogram(cutree(hr, k=5)),
          Colv=NA, dendrogram="row", col=my_palette, density.info="none", trace="none")
```

returns the message:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.dendrogram") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.dendrogram' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Is using `cutree` the correct avenue to explore for plotting a restricted dendrogram?  Is there any easier way to do this akin to matlab?

Comment: It help if you post sample data as well to make a complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Normally each leave corresponds to a row/column of data. Do you want to drop those rows/columns not associated with a leaf? With heatmap.2 there's generally a 1:1 correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what do you mean when you write "selecting number of leaf nodes".

The Rowv parameter in heatmap.2 needs a dendrogram or a TRUE/FALSE value. From the help file:

> Rowv = determines if and how the row dendrogram should be reordered.    By
>   default, it is TRUE, which implies dendrogram is computed and
>   reordered based on row means. If NULL or FALSE, then no dendrogram is
>   computed and no reordering is done. If a dendrogram, then it is used
>   "as-is", ie without any reordering. If a vector of integers, then
>   dendrogram is computed and reordered based on the order of the vector.

So, when using `cutree(hr, k=5)`, you will get a vector of integer (telling you to which cluster each item belong to, in a cut that produces 5 clusters). Using `as.dendrogram` on it will not produce a dendrogram, hence: `Rowv=as.dendrogram(cutree(hr, k=5))`, throws an error.

IF you want to **highlight** some of the branches in your tree, for that I invite you to look into the [dendextend package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend) to see which solution works for you best. Here is an example that may be what you are asking for:

```
library(gplots)
data(mtcars) 
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)

# now let's spice up the dendrograms a bit:
Rowv  <- x %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
   set("branches_k_color", k = 3) %>% set("branches_lwd", 4) %>%
   rotate_DendSer(ser_weight = dist(x))
Colv  <- x %>% t %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
   set("branches_k_color", k = 2) %>% set("branches_lwd", 4) %>%
   rotate_DendSer(ser_weight = dist(t(x)))

heatmap.2(x, Rowv = Rowv, Colv = Colv)
```

With the following output:

[image]

Consider also looking at **the recently published [tutorial of dendextend](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/blob/master/inst/ignored/introduction.html)**, you may want to work with the `branches_attr_by_labels` function (in the tutorial it is under the section: "Adjusting branches based on labels"), with the ability to manipulate dendrograms to create plots such as this:

[image]

If what you want is to remove nodes, and leave only a few of them to be plotted, you should probably just create the heatmap for a subset of the data. You can also look at the `prune` function in dendextend (for the general purpose of looking at smaller dendrograms), but if you would want to use it for a heatmap, it is better to just work with a relevant subset of your data.

Comment: I was running your example, but I got this error: 
`Error: could not find function "%>%"`   I ran this: `Rowv  <- x %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
set("branches_k_color", k = 3) %>% set("branches_lwd", 4) %>%
rotate_DendSer(ser_weight = dist(x))`

Comment: What can I do to fix it?   and also the link of  **tutorial of dendextend** doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify and provide some data...
I do not want to drop any of the rows; instead of plotting/interpreting 831 branches, I would like to interpret 3 branches, and so would like the row dendrogram to be constrained to 3 branches (at height 150) and the corresponding heatmap of all 831 rows to be clustered into the 3 upper branches of the original dendrogram.

```
#Here is a random n=10 subset of my data; which for 10 observed fish has the %of time each spent within     
#a depth bin (Bin1-Bin8)

zz <- "ID Bin1 Bin2 Bin3 Bin4 Bin5 Bin6 Bin7 Bin8
1    0    0    0    0    0  0.0   0.0 100.0
2    0    0    0    0    0  0.0   0.0 100.0
3    0    0    0    0    0  0.0   0.0 100.0
4    0    0    0    0    0 70.8  29.2   0.0
5    0    0    0  100    0  0.0   0.0   0.0
6    0    0    0    0    0  0.0  93.3   6.7
7    0    0    0    0    0 27.5  72.5   0.0
8    0    0    0    0    0 53.5  46.5   0.0
9    0    0    0    0    0  0.0 100.0   0.0
10    0    0    0    0    0  0.0  72.1  27.9 "

TAD <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
IDnames <- TAD[,1]
x<-data.matrix(TAD[,2:ncol(TAD)])
rownames(x) <- IDnames
```

Without worrying about heatmap for the time being, the distance matrix and hclustering is done on the numeric matrix x

```
TAD.dist <- dist(x, method="manhattan", diag=FALSE, upper=FALSE)
TAD.cluster <- hclust(TAD.dist, method="average", members=NULL)
```

a plot of this resultant dendrogram reveals all ten branches,

```
plot(TAD.cluster)
```

but a cutoff height of 150 will restrain to only 3 branches

```
hcd = as.dendrogram(TAD.cluster)
rowDend<- cut(hcd, h = 150)$upper
plot(rowDend)
```

the dendrogram plotted with plot(rowDend) is what I would like to see on the row dendrogram for the following heatmap

```
heatmap.2 (x,
distfun = function(x) dist(x, method='manhattan', diag=FALSE, upper=FALSE),
hclustfun = function(x) hclust(x,method = 'average'),
dendrogram = "row",
#Rowv=rowDend, #this is where I thought I could restrain the row dendrogram
Colv="NA",
trace="none",
)
```

But I can not find any way to restrain the row dendrogram in heatmap for the desired number of interpretable branches.  Plotting all 831 branches is extremely messy.